# Robocopy files without writing permissions / granting temporary writing permission

Tags: windows, permissions, robocopy

I try to robocopy my "C:\Program Files" directory (and further) to D: drive in audit mode during Windows 10 installation with:
`robocopy "C:\Program Files" "D:\Program Files" /E /XJ /COPYALL`

However some folders (e.g. `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`) are owned by `SYSTEM` or `TrustedInstaller`. So, after the directory hierarchy of these are created, writing files is not permitted there and the robocopy task fails and skips it.

Since taking ownership of all these would be an awkward way, I wonder if there's a solution to archive robocopying the Program Files directory.

PS: If someone knows an easier way to relocate Windows Program Data directories to a different drive I'd be very interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested suggestion:

- Get [PSExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).
- Use it to [launch a new command prompt as the SYSTEM](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/10/22/getting-a-cmd-prompt-as-system-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008/).

  - i.e.: `PSExec -i -s -d CMD`, run "As Administrator".

[image: Cmd As SYSTEM]

- Perform the Robocopy from that new command prompt window (so Robocopy runs as the SYSTEM).
- Delete PSExec before exiting Audit Mode.

Comment: This is perfect, and exactly what I needed. Have a huge thanks!

Comment: After all, copying worked perfectly fine using this method. However trying to delete `C:\Program Files` ended in an 'access denied' error again. Can you figure out a solution for that?

Comment: @Reizo You should 1) Mark this answer as accepted based on it solving your problem, and 2) Ask a separate question to address the problem deleting the folder. On the Stack Exchange Q&A sites we generally stick to one question per question. Thanks for participating on SU!

Comment: @Twisty I did mark this question as accepted before I commented at the first place :o
Concerning the second point I have to admit you're very right. (However I found a solution anyway so for anyone who will read this in future: [This](http://www.sordum.org/9416/powerrun-v1-1-run-with-highest-privileges/) tool allows running command line as TrustedInstaller and thus deleting said directory.)
Thanks for keeping everything in order.